# colorInversePrimary and colorShadow is missing in Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, material-components-android

colorInversePrimary  and colorShadow is missing in Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar
my material version is 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha03'

```
 <item name="colorInversePrimary">@color/md_theme_dark_inversePrimary</item>
    <item name="colorShadow">@color/md_theme_dark_shadow</item>
```

this two line.
I get it from material-theme-builder, but when I add into my project it's coming as an error. Other colors are fine.

Comment: I also face same problem. When deleted these two attribute, "android:windowTranslucentStatus" not working properly. I don't know why exactly this happening.

Comment: Check my answer, it's a currently working fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like they are adding more color roles. For now, use the temporary fix with applying attrs.

```
<attr name="colorInversePrimary" format="reference|color" />
<attr name="colorShadow" format="reference|color" />
```